# How To Set Text Colour of HTML Headers

Tags: html, text, colors

Im starting to build my first website for a class at my school. I was having trouble setting the text colour of my two headers in the class .headers.

My Headers (the periods are there because idk how to format HTML here)

```
<h1 align="center" class="headers">All Hail our Eternal Leader</h1>
<h2 align="center" class="headers">Senpai Gabe is with us</h2>
```

CSS

```
h1.headers {color: white;}
```

Comment: `h1.headers` will only match your `<h1>`, not your `<h2>`

Comment: You can use only class name for applying color on both the tag.  .headers {color: white;}   or you can use h1.headers , h2.headers {color: white;}

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
h1 {
        color: white;
    }
        h2{
            color: white;
        }
```

or

```
.headers  {
        color: white;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two different kinds of elements, `<h1>` and `<h2>`. Your CSS is specifying `<h1>` elements with the class name `headers`. There's two things you could try:

Create CSS class for both elements:

```
h1.headers, h2.headers {color: white;}
```

OR, don't specify the element type in your CSS class:

```
.headers {color: white;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
h1 {
   color: #YOURCOLOR;
}
h2 {
   color: #YOURCOLOR;
}
```

or you can use your own class:

```
.headers {
   color: #YOURCOLOR;
}
```